# How non root user able to run on privilige port

Tags: linux, docker

I am expecting the following command to fail with a permission exception because it is running as an unprivileged user. But instead, it appears to succeed.

```sh
% docker run --rm -u nobody  alpine  nc -l 0.0.0.0 443
```

```sh
% docker exec -it b2b471d05398 sh
~ $ id
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nobody)
~ $ ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 nobody    0:00 nc -l 0.0.0.0 443
    8 nobody    0:00 sh
   15 nobody    0:00 ps
~ $ %
```

I have tried to disable various capabilities, but still, none of this prevents the `nc` from running successfully and binding to the port.

```sh
docker run --rm -u nobody --cap-drop=SETUID --cap-drop=NET_BIND_SERVICE --cap-drop=SETFCAP --cap-drop=NET_RAW  alpine  nc -l 0.0.0.0 443
```

In response to David Maze's answer,
I built an image with `Debian GNU/Linux`.

Here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:slim-buster
EXPOSE 80
USER nobody
CMD python -m http.server 80
```

The docker build command

`docker build -t test .`

Still able to bind on a privileged port by **non-root** user

```
docker run  --rm test
```

I also tried this for dropping the capability:

```sh
docker run  --rm --cap-drop=SETUID --cap-drop=NET_BIND_SERVICE --cap-drop=SETFCAP --cap-drop=NET_RAW  test
```

Any idea what should I do to remove the capability and trigger the error that I am trying to reproduce?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the problem here, the 443 port is running only inside the container and not exposed in the external machine. Will you have multiple users inside each container?

Comment: Assuming that you are trying to let Docker take over your _public_ port 443, there is no way really to obtain access to privileged resources without acquiring those privileges. You can limit your privileges by configuring `sudo` to restrict them as much as is feasible; but in this case, being able to run `sudo docker run` is probably already sufficient to take over the system, so it's not really clear how you could usefully limit the privileges of this command. My suggestion would be to simply run it privileged and live with the consequences. (But that's not how you do it.)

Comment: I'm supposed to get the bind exception instead it binding the port. That should be the behavior port numbers less than 1024 shouln't be opened by non-root user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR:

include option `--sysctl "net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=1024"` in your command

---

### Long answer:

#### Introduction

in [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) it is stated that

> Warning
>
> The docker group grants privileges **equivalent** to the root user.

this does not refer to the user you are intending to use inside the container but to your ${USER}. It is **important** because that will **grant all** the things docker can do!

However while nobody is not a proper user that can logon the uid exists and docker will just run the program with that uid. [see here](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/907)

#### Testing the stated issue

I tried the netcat issue, *but I did not find any proper resources on the alpine nc. Testing it seemed to not properly open ports.* 
The python server gives more insight when testing.

If you try the following you will see that the **security** is properly working for the host network.

correctly permission denied:

```
docker run -u nobody --cap-drop=all --network host --rm python:slim-buster python -m http.server 80
```

```
docker run  --cap-drop=all --network host --rm python:slim-buster python -m http.server 80
```

```
docker run -u nobody --network host --rm python:slim-buster python -m http.server 80
```

granted for root ( as you can see from the introduction, you are **root equivalent** ):

```
docker run --network host --rm python:slim-buster python -m http.server 80
```

But yes the *"issue"* exists for bridges:

```
docker run -u nobody --cap-drop=all --rm python:slim-buster python -m http.server 80
```

#### Explanation

Looking around you can find the **docker bridge interface** is not included in the port opening limitation.  Please see [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8460) [merge](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/41030).

And as usual looking at their [tests](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/41030/commits/dae652e2e5e47d99c8febd5bc81df0a3269beb74#diff-e58cb0fff64b4ecbef6aecbd48040c8aacecaa0c5bc23af4002c5ae1f8fafb0dR1261) you will find **"the answer"** to your underlying question.

Permission denied in all 3 flavors **with bridge**

```
docker run -u nobody --cap-drop=all --sysctl "net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=1024" --rm python:slim-buster  python -m http.server 80
```

```
docker run -u nobody --sysctl "net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=1024" --rm python:slim-buster  python -m http.server 80
```

```
docker run --cap-drop=all --sysctl "net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=1024" --rm python:slim-buster  python -m http.server 80
```

And here it is granted correctly for root *(a privileged user, while demanding privileged user for access)*

```
docker run --sysctl "net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=1024" --rm python:slim-buster  python -m http.server 80
```

Comment: I will be away for some time but had to work this out or it would have nagged on me. However it might take a little time until I can respond to comments though.

Comment: when you want to know how something works, look at their tests. proper tests are the best documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Alpine is based on a minimal tool set called [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/), which contains its own implementation of many standard command-line utilities.  The `nc` syntax that BusyBox supports is

```sh
nc -l -p 443 0.0.0.0
```

where `-l` sets up "listen" mode and `-p 443` indicates the listening port.  (Indeed, without the `-p` option, I'd expect BusyBox `nc` to [exit immediately](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/nc.c#n180) with a `-l` option and two positional arguments, and then you wouldn't be able to `docker exec` into the container.)

Without a `-p` option, BusyBox `nc` will [pick an arbitrary port and print it to stderr](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/nc.c#n200).  That won't be a privileged port, which is why you're not getting an error there.  `docker logs` should show the port number, and `netstat` inside the container should show the listener on the alternate port.

Comment: Hi David I have change the image from Alpine to buster, still non root user is able to open the privileged port

Comment: Changing your question so that existing answers are no longer valid is not acceptable behavior on Stack Overflow. However, in this case I feel that this answer was only pointing out a tangential detail anyway.

Comment: The question is still valid @tripleee why the nonroot user is able to open the privileged port even the capability is dropped

Comment: I updated the question to hopefully clarify it. With that, I don't think this answer is relevant any longer.